# Page walkthrough in ARM

Tags: linux, memory-management, linux-kernel, arm, paging

Below is the following code to convert user virtual address to Page Frame Number running on ARMV7 Architecture:

```
static inline uint user_va_to_pfn( unsigned long address )
{
    // Creating instance of Page Global Directory
    //
    pgd_t *pgd;

    // Creating instance of Page Upper Directory
    //
    pud_t *pud;

    // Creating instance of Page Middle Directory
    //
    pmd_t *pmd;

    // Creating instance of Page Table Entries
    //
    pte_t *pte;

    // used for Stored Page frame number
    //
    int pfn;

    pgd = pgd_offset( current->mm, address );

    if ( pgd_none( *pgd ) || pgd_bad( *pgd ) )
    {
        return CMV_ERROR;
    }

    pud = pud_offset( pgd, address );

    if ( pud_none( *pud ) || pud_bad( *pud ) )
    {
        return CMV_ERROR;
    }

    pmd = pmd_offset( pud, address );

    if ( pmd_none( *pmd ) || pmd_bad( *pmd ) )
    {
        return CMV_ERROR;
    }

    pte = pte_offset_kernel( pmd, address );

    if ( !pte )
    {
        return CMV_ERROR;
    }

    pfn = pte_pfn( *pte );

    return ( pfn - PFN_BASE );
}
```

Sometimes, these code is failing with pte = 0x00000000, is this means the virtual address is swapped out
I have also observed, that printing values of pgd, pud, pmd, they are same

```
printk(KERN_ERR "pgd_t:%02x\n", pgd_val(*pgd));
printk(KERN_ERR "pud:%02x\n", pud_val(*pud));
printk(KERN_ERR "pmd:%02x\n", pmd_val(*pmd));
```

What user virtual address will always be present in memory and not swapped out?

Answer (score 0):

Speaking from a general OS/Linux perspective: normally no user virtual address is guaranteed to be present in memory because that's the whole point of virtual memory; i.e. could be kicked out at any time.

However, if you wanted to guarantee a page is in memory, there are ways to pin pages in memory, for instance if you [lock a page](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/pagemap.h#L622) or if you modify the page replacement algorithm to skip pages that satisfy some condition you specify. For instance, in the `shrink_page_list()` [function](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/mm/vmscan.c#L1270) you'll see various conditions (including checking if page is locked) checking to see if the page should be swapped out. You can add your condition there, just keep in mind there are other code paths that might swap out pages you'd have to cover as well.